# How to download a dataset to arbitrary location in Torch?

Tags: lua, torch, luajit

How can I download a dataset to arbitrary location. 
For example:

```
require "dp"
local datasource = dp.BillionWords{context_size=5, train_file="train_tiny.th7"}
```

Attempts to download the dataset into `~/` while I need it to be downloaded to `/media/removable/SD`.

How can I do it in Torch?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I figured it out by reading [init.lua](https://github.com/nicholas-leonard/dp/blob/master/init.lua) for dp package. 
In order to force **Torch** download data to some custom location before running your script do:

```
$ export TORCH_DATA_PATH="/my/new/location"
```